# CloudWatch Alarm Percentage of errors API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

I'm trying to setup and alarm in Cloudwatch using terraform.
My alarm basically needs to check if there is more than 5% of 5xx errors in the gateway during 2 periods of 1 minute.

I've tried the following code but it's not working:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "gateway_error_rate" {
  alarm_name          = "gateway-errors"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  alarm_description   = "Gateway error rate has exceeded 5%"
  treat_missing_data  = "notBreaching"
  metric_name         = "5XXError"
  namespace           = "AWS/ApiGateway"
  period              = 60
  evaluation_periods  = 2
  threshold           = 5
  statistic           = "Average"
  unit                = "Percent"

  dimensions = {
    ApiName = "my-api"
    Stage = "dev"
  }
}
```

Even thee alert is deployed, the data is not displayed.
Doing some tests I've noticed that apparently the unit "percent" is not accepted for this alarm.

Does anyone have an example in `terraform` or `cloudformation` on how to configure this type of alarms?

Comment: The valid unit is `Count`. I think you would need a custom metric, based on ratio of `5XXError` to `Count` for example.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin !, based on your comment I've found this 
 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-metrics-and-dimensions.html so "the Average statistic represents the 5XXError error rate, namely, the total count of the 5XXError errors divided by the total number of requests during the period" so assuming the threshold 1 is 100% of the calls failed, should I also adjust the threshold to 0.05?

Comment: Yes, seems exactly what I suggested. Don't need custom metric then:-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the information provided in the comments by [Marcin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/248823/marcin), I've found [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-metrics-and-dimensions.html) info in the aws documentation:

> *The Average statistic represents the 5XXError error rate, namely, the total count of the 5XXError errors divided by the total number of requests during the period. The denominator corresponds to the Count metric (below).*

My alarm configured in terraform looks as follow:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "gateway_error_rate" {
  alarm_name          = "gateway-errors"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  alarm_description   = "Gateway error rate has exceeded 5%"
  treat_missing_data  = "notBreaching"
  metric_name         = "5XXError"
  namespace           = "AWS/ApiGateway"
  period              = 60
  evaluation_periods  = 2
  threshold           = 0.05
  statistic           = "Average"
  unit                = "Count"

  dimensions = {
    ApiName = "my-api"
    Stage = "dev"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this on CloudFormation and it is working fine, and I use SUM not "percent"

```
  ApiGateway5XXErrorAlarm:
    Type: 'AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm'
    Properties:
      AlarmDescription: 'Api Gateway server-side errors captured'
      Namespace: 'AWS/ApiGateway'
      MetricName: 5XXError
      Dimensions:
      - Name: ApiName
        Value: !Ref ApiGateway
      - Name: Stage
        Value: dev
      Statistic: Sum
      Period: 60
      EvaluationPeriods: 1
      Threshold: 1
      ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold
      AlarmActions:
      - !Ref Alerts
      TreatMissingData: notBreaching
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer! Does this calculate the percentage of errors? I think that your alarm raises when more than one 5XX error is produced in the API Gateway, however what I'm looking for is an alarm calculating percentages, when more than 5% of the total of calls are 5XX.